# Paypal SetExpressCheckout - Do I need a unique token per item?

Tags: paypal, token, express-checkout

Apologies for the simple question but the Paypal documentation is horrendous. I am integrating paypal into a flash game and am using the Digital Goods API with Paypal express checkout. My virtual goods page showcases 4 different items that can be individually paid by clicking a "Buy with Paypal" button under each item. Do I require to generate an individual token for each item? Or is having one token for any type of payment all that is needed?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally think their documentation is pretty good, actually.  There's just a lot off it and you need to know where to look.

Since you're dealing with Express Checkout the [EC Integration Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/) is what you should start with.  Within that is a [section about tokens](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/#id084RN0V0QRO) that notes they're valid for approximately 3 hours.

The tokens are unique per checkout session.  Once the checkout is completed then the token is no longer valid, or if the 3 hours passes it will expire and no longer be valid.  Otherwise, once you get a token you can put as many items in your final DoExpressCheckoutPayment request as you want to and it'll work just fine.

Comment: I ended up reading most of that - I guess I just wasn't confident with what "transaction" meant. Thank you for the clarification.